# Control the Zune Software with SendMessage

Tags: c#, sendmessage, zune

I am wondering if there is a way to pause/play/skip the zune software by using SendMessage on the software? I don't like all the songs the SmartDJ picks and It would be nice to do that with key presses while im playing a fullscreen game.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for zune hoteys and found [project](http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/ZuneKeys-Global-Hotkey-Support-for-Zune.aspx) with open source. It written on Delphi language but I think SendMessage is cross-language command and you find all you need there :)